# MNIST training time in CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

I have created a simple feed forward Neural Network library in `Java` - and I need a benchmark to compare and troubleshoot my library.

Computer specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
- RAM 16.0 GB
- WINDOWS 10 OS
- JVM args: `-Xms1024m` `-Xmx8192m`

Note that I am not using a GPU.

Please list the following specs:

- Computer specs?
- GPU or CPU (CPU is proffered but GPU is good info)
- Number of inputs 784 (this is fixed)
- For each layer:

  - How many nodes?
  - What activation function?
- Output layer:

  - How many nodes? (10 if classification or 1 as regression)
  - What activation function?
- What loss function?
- What gradient descent algorithm (i.e.: vanilla)
- What batch size?
- How many epochs? (not iterations)
- **And finally, what is the training time and accuracy?**

Thank you so much

**Edit**

Just to give an idea of what I am dealing with. I created a network with

- 784 input nodes
- 784 in hidden layer 0
- 256 in hidden layer 1
- 128 in hidden layer 2
- 1 output nodes
- mini-batch size 5
- 16 threads for backprop
  And it has been training for ~8 hours and has only completed 694 iterations - that is not even 20% of one epoch.

How is this done in minutes as I've seen some claims?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want here.  Do you want someone to train a network with  the MNIST dataset and report the performance?

Comment: @rayryeng I am assuming someone already has - and they have the information available

Comment: Probably not - MNIST is a toy dataset and usually just used for demonstration purposes to show that neural networks can achieve higher accuracy and performance within just a few epochs.  Results are quite reproducible regardless of any package or framework you use.  Most likely someone will have to set this up and run it again to give you what you want - that I don't believe many people will want to do.

Comment: @rayryeng Then I ll add a bounty - or Venmo someone :)

Comment: @EdvBeq, you might want to consider spinning up virtual machines of varying specs in AWS, GCP, Azure, etc. and building the desired list yourself :)

Comment: Are you writing the matrix multiplications or dot products yourself? Deep learning frameworks implement these very efficiently and most of the time they use intrinsic functions that take advantage of SIMD to achieve vectorization. If your purpose is to try to match performance or exceed it, it's best that you really don't.

Comment: @rayryeng Java does not have any native matrix libraries so I used regular for loops. I continue this project as a self learning tool. I know I can’t compete with any big framework.

Comment: @EdvBeq got it. Well that's good!

Comment: are you looking to benchmark the model performance, e.g. accuracy or training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 784 input nodes
>   784 in hidden layer 0
>   256 in hidden layer 1
>   128 in hidden layer 2
>   1 output nodes
>   mini-batch size 5

You could do thinner do: 784 => 784/2, 160, 40, batch size at least 50.

And yes event in java, what generally slow, the naive solution must run like **several minutes** **for COMPLETE** train means 10~20 epoch.

How have you implemented it? Do not tell you have a neuron class and each neuron is represented by an instance.

It dont suppose to run so horrible slow. The optimisations i know is to represent second matrix of dot transposed and use strassen-vinograd algorithm, but you do wrong something else

Look at my dot implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JTensor {


private float [] data;// contains data.length

private int width;



public static void dot_T(double [] out, double [] x, double [] y, int wy) {

    int iOut = 0;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < x.length; ix+=wy) {

        for (int iy = 0; iy < y.length;) {

            int ixv = ix;

            int iyLimit = iy + wy;
            double summ = 0;
            for(;iy <iyLimit;) {                    
                summ += x[ixv++] * y[iy++];             

            }
            out[iOut++] = summ;         



        }


    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("generate random");

    int size = 1000;

    double []x = new double [size * size];

    double []y = new double [size * size];

    double []out = new double [size * size];

     for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {            
         x[i] = (double)i   ;       
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {            
         y[i] = (double)i   ;           
    }       

    System.out.println("start ");
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    JTensor.dot_T(out, x,y,size);

    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("elapsed " + ((end- start)/ (1000.0*1000*1000)));

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString( x));
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString( y));
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString( out));


}
```

Comment: "Do not tell you have a neuron class and each neuron is represented by an instance." haha yes - actually I have a class instance for each node and each connection from one node to another. Is that bad?

Comment: OMG... yes. You should do this with only matrix operations - dot product and elementvise operators. Also in java represent matrix as one dimensional array, second matrix is transposed because of sequential access and also like 1d array and look yourself how to do mult to them.

Comment: also it is an illustration how java objects are slow compare to primitive ops

Comment: yes I can see that now - but it was the only way i could wrap my mind around it. I get lost with matrix operations

Comment: ok give me a second i ll find my dot product implementation. I also wrote NN in java long ago for fun

Answer (score 0):

am not really clear about the benchmark you're looking for, there is it performance from training perspective, or accuracy? for accuracy, there are some tools that can do the comparison between the predictions and actuals so you can measure the performance